# When trying to use autofill via vba after inserting rows, the formulas copied are incorrect

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, insert, autofill

I have an dynamic range that counts an x amount of constructions in a different document. It then adds this amount of rows (-3 for the default present rows). After the rows are added, the formulas from the first 3 rows are autofilled to match the range.

The formula in the 1st row is
     "=Materiaal!V14"
The formula in the 2nd row is 
    "=Materiaal!V15"
The formula in the 3rd row is 
    "=Materiaal!V16"

However, after the rows are added it skips an amount of cells
The formula in the 4th row is 
    "=Materiaal!V26"
This should have been 
    "=Materiaal!V27"

I tried to change where the new formulas, to make sure it start in the first row again, but that also won't work

```
Dim add_lines_p2 As Integer, formula_source_p2 As Range, 
formula_destination_p2 As Range
add_lines_p2 = production_numbers_count - 3
add_lines_p2 = add_lines_p2 + 16


'now the command to add the new lines + adding the right formulas
 worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("17" & ":" & add_lines_p2).Insert 
 Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove

Set formula_source_p2 = worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("14:15")
Set formula_destination_p2 = worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("14" & ":" & 
add_lines_p2)
formula_source_p2.AutoFill formula_destination_p2
```

I expected the rows to count up from row 14, but after the default 3 rows, it skips a certain amount of cells.

Comment: Hi Walter, I'm having some issues to determine what the problem is. As far as I can see the code runs as expected. Can you perhaps post your current and expected outputs?

Comment: Hi Plutian, I found my own problem and then realised it isn't visible in this post.
The code has a reference to a cell on a different page. It first added rows on the default page, than it made the reference to the cell.

After that it adds rows on the other page, thereby shifting the cell reference down.

Excuses for the therefor "bad" question...

Comment: No problem, it's always encouraged to answer your own question as it shows you've learned something. But as I understand your added rows messed with the cell reference within the same range, which would then shift. Always be careful with named ranges when adding cells in between because problems like this arise. I recommend always adding after the used range instead if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however the range is added after the used range so that wasn't the problem. I use multiple sheets over which the rows are added.

What i did was in the first sheet add rows and reference to the second sheet. So it was still correct. But then the code added new rows on the second sheet, thereby shifting the referenced cells down

I will put the original code in the next comment

Comment: worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("17" & ":" & add_lines_p2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove

    Set formula_source_p2 = worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("14:15")
    Set formula_destination_p2 = worksheet_uitsplitsing.Rows("14" & ":" & 
    add_lines_p2)
    formula_source_p2.AutoFill formula_destination_p2


    Excel.Worksheets("Materiaal").Rows("17" & ":" & add_lines_p2).Insert 
    Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove

So the reference was made before the rows on the other sheet were added

Answer (score 0):

I found my own problem and then realised it isn't visible in this post.
The code has a reference to a cell on a different page. It first added rows on the default page, than it made the reference to the cell.

After that it adds rows on the other page, thereby shifting the cell reference down.

Excuses for the therefor "bad" question...